# How can I compute and display on browser elapsed time between 2 HTML requests generated on J2EE/JSF server?

Tags: javascript, html, jakarta-ee, primefaces, elapsedtime

Since more than 2 years, I display in StatusBar of each HTML pages

1. the time of the last action YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
2. the elapsed time computed on SERVER.

Sometimes, DISPLAYED elapsed time is very short (3 seconds), but the user has waited more than 10 seconds !

The difference is Network delay and Browser time needed to display the page !

I'm now interesting to display FULL delay and I see 2 possibles solutions.

**Solution 1.**

Using only Javascript to save START of request and to compute elapsed time when request is displayed again. The START time must me saved somewhere ! But where ? In Cookies !

Example: when user click on a Button, the OnClick() event save the START time just before posting message to J2EE server. J2EE server generate new message and post it. In Browser, Javascript intercept new server message and display computed elapsed time on StatusBar.

**Solution 2.**

The START time is recorded using JavaScript and is transmitted to J2EE application that sent it again in HTML page. The elapsed time must be calculated by Javascript after result message has been received.

**Solution 3.**

Is there a another solution to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the start time to localStorage, then every new page can pull back localStorage and compute the difference.  Just another possible solution.

Comment: Interesting. But I have a special case that is ... When I click on a row in a table the item clicked is loaded on ANOTHER Chrome tab. It is in the same session. Must I use localStorage or sessionStorage ?